# Cloning private GitHub repository using Ansible

Tags: github, ansible, github-api

I have an Ansible playbook that takes the public key (that is present on my source machine) and copies it to the new remote server since this key is already added to my github account.

```
 - name: send key to remote deploy user
     copy: src=/home/vagrant/code/id_rsa dest=home/priv_key owner=root group=root mode=0600

  - name: Clone repo
    git:
      repo: git@github.ncsu.edu:rcoutin/BOT.git
      dest: home/app
      key_file: ../priv_key
      accept_hostkey: yes
      force: yes
    become: no
```

However, the clone repo task fails and tells me the permission is 0644 for the SSH key and can be viewed by others which is not accepted.

I did set the mode to 0600 in the send key task but it still says its 0644.

Any help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

**First and foremost**, it is a terrible practice to duplicate private keys, worse yet to leave them scattered on non-protected machines. Read and follow: [Using SSH agent forwarding](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/).

---

Regarding the problem in the question (which should never even come up if you used SSH agent forwarding), you are blatantly wrong in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493973/cloning-private-github-repository-using-ansible/47496405#comment81943340_47493973):

> home/app is in a folder called /home/app on the remote machine and ../priv_key is in the parent of the /app directory

If you specify `key_file: ../priv_key` along `dest: home/app`, Git executable will look for the `priv_key` file not in the "*parent of the /app directory*", but in the parent of `home` directory (where seemingly you have another copy of `private_key` with wrong permissions).

> Any help on how to fix this?

Don't use relative paths, especially if you are not sure what you are doing and not willing to troubleshoot yourself.

---

Besides, if you limit access to the `priv_key` to `root` user only, as you do in your first task, you won't be able to read it with `vagrant` user in the second (which you explicitly specify with `become: no`).